# Задача на Python "Уникальные элементы"

Tags: python

> Дан список. Выведите те его элементы, которые встречаются в списке
> только один раз. Элементы нужно выводить в том порядке, в котором они
> встречаются в списке. В данной задаче запрещено пользоваться всеми
> операциями над списками (find, count, index и так далее).
>
> Входные данные
>
> Вводится список целых чисел. Все числа списка находятся на одной
> строке.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> Выведите ответ на задачу.

Не могу решить, вот мой код, но он проходит не все тесты:

```
a = input().split()
for i in range(len(a)):
    c=a[0:i]+a[i+1:-1]
    if a[i] not in c:
        print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по всему ваш код не проходит тесты из=за этой строки:

```
c=a[0:i]+a[i+1:-1]
#              ^^----!
```

уберите `-1`, должно работать

```
c=a[:i] + a[i+1:]
```

Comment: а можно тогда вопрос?я просто новичок в программировании и многих аспектов не понимаю. -1 это же индекс конечного элемента и я беру срез от i+1 до конечного ,но и ваш вариант тоже берет от i+1 до конечного,так вот, в чем разница между ними?

Comment: @MERERO по правилам синтаксиса левая граница входит в срез, а правая не входит, то есть  для `[:i]` i в срез не войдет

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо за обьяснение

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через словарь. Прохожусь по каждому элементу списка и прибавляю его счётчик внутри словаря. В Python 3.6 и выше словарь сохраняет элементы словаря в том же порядке в котором вы туда их добавляете. Т.е. мы добавляем элементы в словарь в порядке, таком же, как и в начальном списке. Идея делать через срезы и проверку через in плохая, так как это сильно повлияет на производительность.

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
cnt = {}
for el in a:
    if el not in cnt:
        cnt[el] = 1
    else:
        cnt[el] += 1


for el in cnt:
    if cnt[el] == 1:
        print(el)
```

Comment: Хм. Вам же запрещено использовать стандартные операции над списками, а операции со словарем - это ещё более высокоуровневые вещи.

Comment: это верно,словари я не проходил еще))

Answer (score 0):

нашел вот такое решение,но если честно я его не понял

```
a = [int(q) for q in input().split()]
for i in range(len(a)):
     for j in range(len(a)):
          if i != j and a[i] == a[j]:
               break
     else:
          print(a[i], end=' ')
```

Comment: А что тут непонятного?  Каждый элемент в списке `a` сравнивается с каждым другим, если не находится дубликат, то выводится.

Answer (score 0):

По другому сделал: сравниваю каждый с каждым, и если количество "несовпадений" равно "количеству элементов" -1 (это чтобы исключить сравнение с самим собой), то добавляю его в список.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b = []
k = 0
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    for j in range (0, len(a)):
        if a[i] != a[j]:
            k += 1
    if k == len(a) - 1:
        b.append(a[i])
    k = 0
print(' '.join(str(i) for i in b))
```

Comment: При первом же совпадении значения, если индекс другой, можно останавливаться, как здесь:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1473963/291659

Comment: То решение по ссылке вообще классное. Я свое придумывал т.к. еще не проходил else в цикле for ))) а сейчас прочитал и кааак понял)))